# How to create instance of service class in constructor of a static class

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I have a parameter service class like following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { Common } from './common';
import { CacheService } from "ionic-cache";

@Injectable()
export class PMService {  

    constructor(public http: Http, public comm: Common, private cache: CacheService) {        

    }
...
}
```

I use this service class in pages normally like this:

```
import { PMService } from '../../providers/pm-service';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage { 
    myParameters;

    constructor(private pm: PMService ..) {                                    

    }

    getMyParameter(){
       this.pm.getParameters("ParameterKey").then(result=>{
         this.myParameters= result;
       });
    }
 ...
}
```

I created another class that includes static methods. I want to initialize a static property in constructor of this class. I can not use constructor(private pm: PMService) {} because of static property. I tried following code but it expects constructor arguments. What is the right way to do what i want?

```
import { PMService } from "./pm-service";

function construct(target: any) {
    target.construct();
}

@construct
export class Manager {

    private static counter: number = 0;
    private static defaultManagerValue: number = 0;

    static construct() {
        var pm = new PMService();
        this.defaultManagerValue = // I want to get this value from PMService;
    }

    public static incrementCounter() {
        this.counter++;
    }

    public isCounterEqualMyParameter(){
        return this.counter == this.defaultManagerValue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is manager for, why does it need to be static? Having your own things outside of the DI system is going to make it very complicated.

Comment: I use manager class to count user actions in all pages. For examle; if user reached 10 actions i will show an interstitial advertisement. I tried static to follow counter in all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a static class, but a [*Singleton*](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) instead. A Singleton is a class with only one instance across the application, citing the angular docs:

> A singleton service is a service for which only one instance exists in an app.

You can change your static methods to instance methods, and change the definition to:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Manager {
  private counter: number = 0;
  private defaultManagerValue: number = 0;

  // ...
}
```

This way you can use DI freely in the constructor, while having the same desired effect.